# Can't purge message on RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

G'day everyone.

I've got a very strange trouble in RabbitMQ.
I have a Queue with just 1 message. I tried many ways to purge it. I erased the queue, but when I started it again, the 1 message still there. I tried to purge messages, to Ack message requeue false and all this options return to me a message that the queue is empty. I tried to reboot the rabbit too and the 1 message still there as well. It's like a phantom message.

The rabbitmq is running in a pod on kubernetes.
Anyone has a clue for how to deal with it?
Thanks!

UPDATE:
Problem solved. I just restarted the pod where the rabbit is running and this phantom message disappeared.

Comment: Did you use the [rabbitmq management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) ? From the web interface you can easily purge your messages (Queues tab)

Comment: yes, I did. I solved the problem just restarting the pod where the rabbit is running.